# the positive semidefiniteness of a Hermitian Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a square matrix $\mathbf{A}$ whose $(m,n)^{\text{th}}$ element is defined as $\mathbf{A}_{mn}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\imath(m-n)\pi\cos\phi}d\phi$ where $\imath=\sqrt{-1}$. It is obvious that $\mathbf{A}$ is Toeplitz and Hermitian. But whether $\mathbf{A}$ is positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any column vector ${\bf v}$, 
$$ {\bf v}^H A {\bf v} = 2 \int_{-\pi}^\pi {\bf V(\phi)}^H {\bf V(\phi)} \ d\phi \ge 0$$
where $${\bf V}(\phi) = \sum_n \exp(-i \pi n \cos(\phi)) v_n$$